# UIImage Saving image with file name on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, sandbox, save-image

How can I save an image (like using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() method) with a filename of my choice to the private/var folder?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Kenny, you had the answer! For illustration I always think code is more helpful.

```
//I do this in the didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img method

NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0);


//save to the default 100Apple(Camera Roll) folder.   

[imageData writeToFile:@"/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/customImageFilename.jpg" atomically:NO];
```

Comment: A sample saving to the documents folder 
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpg", documentsDirectory, fileName];

NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(drawImage.image, 1.0);
[imageData writeToFile:filePath2 atomically:NO];

Comment: [imageData writeToFile:@"/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/customImageFilename.jpg" atomically:NO]; What is this private/var/mobile folder?
Is this a standard place to write out a file in ios?

Comment: The question is, if apple will allow an app with that code... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884003/will-the-app-get-rejected-if-you-write-image-to-private-var-mobile-media-dcim-1?lq=1

Comment: Is this still allowed..? Doesn't seem to be a filepath I have write access to.

Answer (score 10):

`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()` is only used for saving to the photos camera roll. To save to a custom folder, you need to convert the UIImage into NSData with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation()`, then save this NSData to anywhere you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code, without use of ALAssetsLibrary...

```
NSString *fileName;

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

if( [picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera )
            {
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,nil, nil, nil);
                [self performSelector:@selector(GetImageName) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
            }
            else
            {
                NSURL *refURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
                PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[refURL] options:nil];
                fileName = [[result firstObject] filename];
            }
}];

-(void)GetImageName
{
 NSString *str =@"";
 PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
 fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];
 PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:fetchOptions];

if (fetchResult != nil && fetchResult.count > 0) {

    str = [[fetchResult lastObject] filename];
}

fileName = str;
}
```