# Will the app get rejected if you write image to /private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/ directly?

Tags: iphone, image, appstore-approval

Instead of using UIImageWirteToSavedAlbum, is it safe to write your image to /private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/ directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without consulting the actual developer contracts at all, I feel safe in saying "Count on it, you will get rejected".

(Besides, is this even possible, given the sandboxing?)

**Edit:** The iPhone Application Programming Guide says that "for security purposes, your application is placed in its own directory and is limited to reading and writing files in that directory only." If that isn't actually the case (i.e. you **can** write to `/private/var/...` anyway, I'm pretty sure it's still "forbidden").

Comment: Yes. You can write to that folder - the thumbnail will not be created automatically as UIImageWirteToSavedAlbum do. 

Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264039/uiimage-saving-image-with-file-name-on-the-iphone

Comment: I see. Updated my answer with some actual data.