# How to store image in program (not in photo library)

Tags: iphone, xcode

I what to store images with below code but occur error,How should i store images(not in photo library in program like this method)?

```
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[array addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a"]];
[array addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b"]];
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SaveCartoons"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setObject:array forKey:@"1"];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:dict toFile:fullPath];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code up there is likely not to save.

For starters, UIImage is not something that can be easily archived.

Look at the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264039/uiimage-saving-image-with-file-name-on-the-iphone) and convert your UIImage to NSData and then you can add that to your mutable array.