# Xcode Saving A Photo in the app

Tags: xcode, string, save, photo

i am working on an app that has an image view at the top, which fills a third of the screen.My question is, I want to be able to have the user press a button and pick any photo he/she likes and have the app save it. This way when they close the app and re open, the photo will still be there. I'm new to xcode and I do apologize if there was already a question like this out there. I wasn't able to find what i was looking for. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve this you need to:

1. Ask the user to select an image from his library ([here's how](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/28/getting-images-from-the-iphone-photo-library-or-camera-using-uiimagepickercontroller/))
2. Save the image the user selected to your app's sandbox ([here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264039/uiimage-saving-image-with-file-name-on-the-iphone))
3. Load that image into the UIImageView at startup ([here's how to save/load small amount of data](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/), in your case you just need to save the location of the image to load it at startup)