# Taking Screen Shot of App to Use During Animation

Tags: screenshot, viewwillappear, viewdidappear

I'm trying to cover up some changes that take place in my view during the transition between `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` and would like to take a screen shot during or immediately before `viewWillDisappear` and then display it during `viewWillAppear`.

I know that a few years ago Apple allowed us to use `UIGetScreenImage`, but that is no longer the case. What is the best way to grab an image of the screen for these purposes now that they have taken away `UIGetScreenImage`?

(Any further advice on how to accomplish the rest of my goal would also be appreciated!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the screen shot of the screen by calling -renderInContext method of CALayer on your top view like this.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];   
UIImage *imgScreenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

here, imgScreenShot is the desired image. enjoy programming!

Comment: Great! I'll give this a go. Where can I find the image once it's taken?

Comment: once you have the UIImage object, than you can simply use it your code  or save it in document directory for later viewing, check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264039/uiimage-saving-image-with-file-name-on-the-iphone) for saving image into a file