# Programmatically save image by specifying name in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

Saving an image by capturing from screen into photo album is fine. But while using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum method for saving an image image got saved in numbers manner like 1, 2, 3 and so on.

Can we specify name while saving an image into photo album? or any other alternative approch to this.

Any help and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: refer
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264039/uiimage-saving-image-with-file-name-on-the-iphone>

Comment: Hello AJG: if @Bhu_zX's question doesn't help you, it might be worthwhile to edit your question to show the code of what you have tried so far.