# How to save an image to iTunes file sharing

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, file-sharing

I like to save  an image called `img` to the iTunes file sharing folder. Can someone please tell me how?

Comment: If you simply store your img in Document Directory it will be visible in iTunes File Sharing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264039/uiimage-saving-image-with-file-name-on-the-iphone

Comment: Do you want something like this http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app

Comment: @George OK, can you please tell me where to place the file, so the file is visible in iTunes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is sample code:

```
NSArray paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpg", documentsDir, filename];

NSData data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0); 
[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
```

**Also about iTunes file sharing:**

You should go to `Info.plist` and add row

`Application supports iTunes file sharing` to `YES`

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to enable the iTunes Filesharing in xcode

Comment: Keep in mind that if you enable that `info.plist` key and don't mention it anywhere in the app or iTunes app description, your app will get rejected.